# Lumen route parameter not working with a dot

Tags: lumen

I need to find a user by email.

So i have try to route on lumen like
/user/email/abc@test.com

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/email/abc@test.com
```

routes/web.php

```
$router->get('/user/email/{email}', ['middleware' => ['cors','auth'], 'uses' =>  'UserController@getUserByEmail']);
```

When i have include a DOT(.) the result shows like

*"The requested resource /user/email/abc@test was not found on this server."*

Otherwise the result is fine.

Please advice how do i route like these scenarios or it is possible or not.
Sorry for my Bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to take email from request body and not from url.
In your function get the email from request. see this example:

```
 public function getUserByEmail(Request $request){

            $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'required',
            ]);
             $email = $request->email;
             //then the rest of your code logic
 }
```

route will be now like this:

```
$router->get('/user/email', ['middleware' => ['cors','auth'], 'uses' =>  'UserController@getUserByEmail']);
```